# Using ffmpeg to convert voice recording captured by HTML5

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg, html5-audio

I'm building an HTML5 voice recording software with visualizer.I want the user when recording the voice, and after uploading the file as wave in a blob (server-side), the user should be able to select the audio format of that file using ffmpeg. what I Have achieved so far is uploading the file as wave.what I still want to do is:

- On the server
- side pick your preferable web programming framework
- The web programming framework accepts the upload and stores the file on the server
- The web programming framework runs a ffmpeg (command line) which processes the file
- The user can download the processed file

here is my code so far:

```
// variables
var leftchannel = [];
var rightchannel = [];
var recorder = null;
var recording = false;
var recordingLength = 0;
var volume = null;
var audioInput = null;
var sampleRate = 44100;
var audioContext = null;
var context = null;
var outputString;



if (!navigator.getUserMedia)
    navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
    navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
    navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
    navigator.msGetUserMedia;

if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
    navigator.getUserMedia({
        audio: true
    }, success, function (e) {
        alert('Error capturing audio.');
    });
} else alert('getUserMedia not supported in this browser.');



function getVal(value) {

    // if R is pressed, we start recording
    if (value == "record") {
        recording = true;
        // reset the buffers for the new recording
        leftchannel.length = rightchannel.length = 0;
        recordingLength = 0;
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = "Recording now...";

        // if S is pressed, we stop the recording and package the WAV file
    } else if (value == "stop") {

        // we stop recording
        recording = false;
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = "Building wav file...";

        // we flat the left and right channels down
        var leftBuffer = mergeBuffers(leftchannel, recordingLength);
        var rightBuffer = mergeBuffers(rightchannel, recordingLength);
        // we interleave both channels together
        var interleaved = interleave(leftBuffer, rightBuffer);



        var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(44 + interleaved.length * 2);
        var view = new DataView(buffer);

        // RIFF chunk descriptor
        writeUTFBytes(view, 0, 'RIFF');
        view.setUint32(4, 44 + interleaved.length * 2, true);
        writeUTFBytes(view, 8, 'WAVE');
        // FMT sub-chunk
        writeUTFBytes(view, 12, 'fmt ');
        view.setUint32(16, 16, true);
        view.setUint16(20, 1, true);
        // stereo (2 channels)
        view.setUint16(22, 2, true);
        view.setUint32(24, sampleRate, true);
        view.setUint32(28, sampleRate * 4, true);
        view.setUint16(32, 4, true);
        view.setUint16(34, 16, true);
        // data sub-chunk
        writeUTFBytes(view, 36, 'data');
        view.setUint32(40, interleaved.length * 2, true);


        var lng = interleaved.length;
        var index = 44;
        var volume = 1;
        for (var i = 0; i < lng; i++) {
            view.setInt16(index, interleaved[i] * (0x7FFF * volume), true);
            index += 2;
        }

        var blob = new Blob([view], {
            type: 'audio/wav'
        });

        // let's save it locally

        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = 'Handing off the file now...';
        var url = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(blob);

        var li = document.createElement('li');
        var au = document.createElement('audio');
        var hf = document.createElement('a');

        au.controls = true;
        au.src = url;
        hf.href = url;
        hf.download = 'audio_recording_' + new Date().getTime() + '.wav';
        hf.innerHTML = hf.download;
        li.appendChild(au);
        li.appendChild(hf);
        recordingList.appendChild(li);

    }
}


function success(e) {

    audioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
    context = new audioContext();


    volume = context.createGain();

    // creates an audio node from the microphone incoming stream(source)
    source = context.createMediaStreamSource(e);

    // connect the stream(source) to the gain node
    source.connect(volume);

    var bufferSize = 2048;

    recorder = context.createScriptProcessor(bufferSize, 2, 2);

    //node for the visualizer
    analyser = context.createAnalyser();
    analyser.smoothingTimeConstant = 0.3;
    analyser.fftSize = 512;

    splitter = context.createChannelSplitter();
    //when recording happens
    recorder.onaudioprocess = function (e) {

        if (!recording) return;
        var left = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
        var right = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(1);

        leftchannel.push(new Float32Array(left));
        rightchannel.push(new Float32Array(right));
        recordingLength += bufferSize;

        // get the average for the first channel
        var array = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
        analyser.getByteFrequencyData(array);

        var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
        // clear the current state
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1000, 325);
        var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 300);
        gradient.addColorStop(1, '#000000');
        gradient.addColorStop(0.75, '#ff0000');
        gradient.addColorStop(0.25, '#ffff00');
        gradient.addColorStop(0, '#ffffff');
        // set the fill style
        ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
        drawSpectrum(array);

        function drawSpectrum(array) {
            for (var i = 0; i < (array.length); i++) {
                var value = array[i];
                ctx.fillRect(i * 5, 325 - value, 3, 325);
            }

        }
    }

    function getAverageVolume(array) {
        var values = 0;
        var average;

        var length = array.length;

        // get all the frequency amplitudes
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            values += array[i];
        }

        average = values / length;
        return average;
    }

    // we connect the recorder(node to destination(speakers))
    volume.connect(splitter);
    splitter.connect(analyser, 0, 0);

    analyser.connect(recorder);
    recorder.connect(context.destination);

}




function mergeBuffers(channelBuffer, recordingLength) {
    var result = new Float32Array(recordingLength);
    var offset = 0;
    var lng = channelBuffer.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < lng; i++) {
        var buffer = channelBuffer[i];
        result.set(buffer, offset);
        offset += buffer.length;
    }
    return result;
}

function interleave(leftChannel, rightChannel) {
    var length = leftChannel.length + rightChannel.length;
    var result = new Float32Array(length);

    var inputIndex = 0;

    for (var index = 0; index < length;) {
        result[index++] = leftChannel[inputIndex];
        result[index++] = rightChannel[inputIndex];
        inputIndex++;
    }
    return result;
}


function writeUTFBytes(view, offset, string) {
    var lng = string.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < lng; i++) {

        view.setUint8(offset + i, string.charCodeAt(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: What server-side tech are you using? Where is your server-side code? And finally, there is a [Javascript FFMPEG implementation](http://bgrins.github.io/videoconverter.js/) so you wouldn't have to send it server-side if you don't want to.

Comment: ok if I don't want to use the server-side,how can I use the ffmpeg to let the user convert files?

Comment: [The docs](http://bgrins.github.io/videoconverter.js/#docs) show you how it takes a `UInt8Array` input. Then you just pass in the required parameters as you would with the command-line app

Comment: I'm sorry for asking so much but I'm new to all that.anyway where do I add the command-line app?and what should files should be added to my project besides the worker.js?in other words how do I introduce the ffmpeg to my project?